# Integrating Neo4J and Terracotta?

Tags: distributed, ehcache, neo4j, terracotta

Has anyone tried or even thought about using a terracotta solution (i.e. ehcache) to run/store Neo4J?

I understand Neo4J has High Availability, but that's really just replication.  Want I really want is a distributed graph solution, hence, neo4j on something like ehcache.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Running graph databases efficiently across multiple hosts is very challenging

This article on Cache Sharding explains one solution:

http://jim.webber.name/2011/02/23/abe72f61-27fb-4c1b-8ce1-d0db7583497b.aspx

Note particularly the statement: "partitioning graphs across physical instances is a notoriously difficult way to scale graph data", referring to a previous article that discusses the details of why this is a hard problem:

http://jim.webber.name/2011/02/16/3b8f4b3d-c884-4fba-ae6b-7b75a191fa22.aspx